# Whenever my function tries to execute in the Form constructor it just loops to previous statement

Tags: c#, forms

I am kind of new to C# and I'm developing a form application... It's something like a game. Whenever the constructor executes the function it just causes the constructor to run again! Here is the constructor:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessageBox.Show("You get 1 cookie for logging in!");
        setScore();
        score = Convert.ToInt32(setScr) + 1;
        label2.Text = score.ToString();
        setProgressBar(CheckMP());
        timer1.Interval = 1500;
        timer1.Start();

        readAndSetAchievements(); // THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT 
                                  //CAUSES THE CONSTRUCTOR TO LOOP!!!
    }
```

Here is the function:

```
        public void readAndSetAchievements()
    {
        Achievements ach1 = new Achievements(); // ACHIEVEMENTS IS ANOTHER FORM THAT I       
                                                // AM CREATING AN INSTANCE OF BECAUSE I
                                                // WANT TO USE VARIABLES AND FUNCTIONS 
                                                // FROM IT 

        using (StreamReader ar = new StreamReader("achievements.txt"))
        {
            achCheckStr[0] = ar.ReadLine();
            achCheckStr[1] = ar.ReadLine();

            if (achCheckStr[0] == ach1.ach1_StillBurning)
            {
                ach1.setAchievements(1);
            }
            else if (achCheckStr[1] == ach1.ach2_Faster)
            {
                ach1.setAchievements(2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please someone help... Tell me where I am wrong (I think it's with the way I'm trying to use the Achievements form class but I don't know how to do it otherwise)... Thanks in advance! :)

Here is the whole Achievements form class:

```
public partial class Achievements : Form
{
    Form1 cha = new Form1();

    public string ach1_StillBurning = "ach1_StillBurning.jpg";
    public string ach2_Faster = "ach2_Faster.jpg";

    public Achievements()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void setAchievements(int a)
    {
        using (StreamWriter aw = new StreamWriter("achievements.txt"))
        {
            switch (a)
            { 
                case 1:
                    aw.WriteLine(ach1_StillBurning);
                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ach1_StillBurning);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    aw.WriteLine(ach2_Faster);
                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ach2_Faster);
                    break;
            }
        }
    } 

    private void Achievements_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cha.readAndSetAchievements();
    }
}
```

Here you guys go! :)

Comment: Show the constructor for `Achievements`.

Comment: Show the `Timer.Tick` Event for `timer1`

Comment: here you go your first line of `Achievements`: `Form1 cha = new Form1();`

Comment: The timer has nothing to do with it. It's tracking a picturebox :)

Comment: Yes I saw that I am creating an instance of Form1... But I need to use items from it can I do it somehow without provoking the constructor?

Comment: What @Bolu said is correct... It's looping the constructor because you're recursively calling the constructor

Comment: Can I use objects from form1 without provoking the constructor?

Comment: If they're static but the design of that is not good. You should just create an object that keeps the whole state of your application and pass it between the two forms.

Comment: Some kind of example please Brandon? Sorry that is, if it's not going to trouble you...

Comment: And you are calling `form1.readAndSetAchievements();` from `Achievements_Load`? it's a double loop? I run out of words.. can you just provide your idea behind the code? what if you just remove `Form1 cha = new Form1();` and `Achievements_Load` event handler all together from your `Achievements` class?

Comment: No, it's not troubling... I'll post as an answer so I have more room

Comment: what if you just remove `Form1 cha = new Form1();` and `Achievements_Load` event handler all together from your `Achievements` class? I didn't see any use of them besides causing the deadlock?

Comment: Well I want to run the readAndSetAchievements() function from Form1... To set the achievements in the Achievements form... I really mashed it up but is there a quick fix to this instead of me completely reformatting this?

Comment: Sounds like you have a circular dependency here. While this isn't an answer for you, here is what that means: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency

Comment: 1. move `readAndSetAchievements()` to `Achievements`; 2. remove `Achievements ach1 = new Achievements();` from `readAndSetAchievements()`; 3. remove `Form1 cha = new Form1();` from `Achievements`; 4. change `cha.readAndSetAchievements();` in `Achievements_Load` to `this.readAndSetAchievements();`; 5. change `readAndSetAchievements();` in `form1` to `Achievements ach1 = new Achievements();`.

Comment: Thanks I'll try resolving this Circular dependency by Bolu's solution and I'll be right back with an edit! :)

Comment: EDIT: Bolu you are gold... Many thanks for solving this puzzle for me buddy! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is what I came up with. I had to make some assumptions though because when reading your code, some stuff didn't make sense. I've noted those.

Edit: Keep in mind, I didn't actually test this code because I didn't create the `Timer1` object. You should only have to make minimal changes, if any.

Here is the code for Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessageBox.Show("You get 1 cookie for logging in!");
        setScore();
        score = Convert.ToInt32(setScr) + 1;
        label2.Text = score.ToString();
        setProgressBar(CheckMP());
        timer1.Interval = 1500;
        timer1.Start();

        //Assuming this is the first use of the Achievements object.
        Achievements.AchievementsFile = "achievements.txt";

    }


}
```

In a separate file, this is the Achievements Form.

```
    private partial class AchievementsForm : Form
    {

        public AchievementsForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Achievements_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> allAchievements = Achievements.ReadAchievements();
            //Do stuff with the achievements
        }
    }
```

In another separate file, this is the new Achievements class. This is what I meant by breaking it out to move the functionality out of the forms.

```
public static class Achievements
    {
        private static string _stillBurning = "ach1_StillBurning.jpg";
        private static string _faster = "ach2_Faster.jpg";

        public static string AchievementsFile { get; set; }

        public static Image SetAchievementFromAchievementCode(int a)
        {
            Image answer;
            using (StreamWriter aw = new StreamWriter(Achievements.AchievementsFile))
            {

                switch (a)
                {
                    case 1:
                        aw.WriteLine(_stillBurning);
                        answer = Image.FromFile(ach1_StillBurning);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        aw.WriteLine(_faster);
                        answer = Image.FromFile(ach2_Faster);
                        break;
                }
            }

            return answer;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> ReadAchievements()
        {
            List<string> answer = new List<string>();

            using (StreamReader ar = new StreamReader(Achievements.AchievementsFile))
            {
                while (!ar.EndOfStream)
                    answer.Add(ar.ReadLine());                    

            }

            return answer;
        }

    }
```

I noticed when reading your code that you essentially had this logic (or similar)

> Call a function to read and set achievements, which called a function
>   to read achievements, which then circularly called the same function
>   again.

I've separated into a Read and a Set. The `SetAchievementFromAchievementCode` function takes the same integer you were using before, writes it to the same file, and then returns you an `Image` that you're free to use whereever/however you want. The `ReadAchievements()` method will give you a full list of all the achievements in the file.

I know it's a bit of overkill, but hopefully that helps. And, whaddaya know... It's lunch time now.